# Can't draw signature on iOS with Nativescript-drawingPad

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

Suddenly I could not draw signature in my NS6 app on iOS device. It was working well with NS5 and I have tried to upgrade the drawingPad still no result.And I don't have any error message on log as well. Does anybody have idea?

xml:

```
xmlns:DrawingPad="nativescript-drawingpad" 
    shownModally="onShownModally" loaded="loaded" unloaded="unloaded" id="modalComponentBox">  
    <ScrollView>
    <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto" id="modalPage">
        <StackLayout row="0">
            <Label text="{{ componentName }}" class="h2" textWrap="true"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal" class="m-l-20 m-r-20" horizontalAlignment="right">
            <Button text="&#xf00d;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="clearSignature"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout row="2">
                <DrawingPad:DrawingPad
                    id="drawingPad"
                    height="200"
                    maxWidth="400"
                    borderColor="#99AAB3"
                    backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                    marginRight="40"
                    margin="20"
                    borderWidth="2"
                    penColor="#99AAB3" penWidth="2" 
                    backgroundColor="#fcfaef"  />
        </StackLayout>
```

and JS:

```
exports.captureSignature = function (args) {
    var drawingPad = page.getViewById("drawingPad");
    drawingPad.getDrawing().then( (res) => {

        try {
            var imgSrc = imageSourceModule.fromNativeSource(res);
            var imgBase64 = imgSrc.toBase64String("png", 100);

            closeCallback(imgBase64, true);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error ---> "+error);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you please add more details? You couldn't draw at all or the pad is unresponsive to the touches? Which version of iOS you are testing it with & what device you are using? Can you try uploading a GIF of the issue

Comment: @Manoj Sometimes I see some dots on simulator(iOS version 13.2.2) while trying to draw. And on my device (iphone 6 iOS version 13.1) I can't draw at all.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the problem. It may not be {N}, but the new iOS 13 feature. It allows you to swipe down and close the modal dialog, I believe when you try to draw, it interferes with the modal swipe down. A quick workaround is to use a fullscreen modal.

Comment: @Manoj Ok.. But, My modal does not close down as long as I am not clicking the the cancel button. Even when I have some dots after clicking many times on simulator, I can save and use those dots.

Comment: Yes, as already mentioned the touches are overridden but even when the swipe action is disabled. Did you try using a fullscreen modal yet?

Comment: @Manoj-- Jahpana tussi great ho.. Problem solved with fullscreen :D

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13 allows user to close a modal dialog by swiping it down. This gesture interferes with drawing pad even when it's disabled.

Using a fullscreen modal dialog fixes the issue. I didn't find the time to debug further for a fix that can solve the issue in non-fullscreen modal. I will update the post if I do.